# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, version=14.0.0.0

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, version=14.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publicroken=89845dc8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. the system cannot find the find the file specified.

I am getting this error in SQLite / SQL Server Compact toolbox - I am using Visual Studio 2015 and

Comment: I am not sure what this could have to do with Sqlite. One is file based and the other is server based. Have you used the nuget manager to install this?